# Class constructor using object of another class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

In this code, I would like to use an object of class birthday, the constructors of class Date are:

```
    Date(unsigned int y, unsigned int m, unsigned int d);
    Date(string yearMonthDay); // yearMonthDay must be in format "yyyy/mm/dd"
```

But I'm getting an error: "No default constructor exist for class Date"

```
class Person {

public:
    Person(std::string name, char gender, Date birthday);
    string getName();
    char getGender();
    int getYear();
    int getMonth();
    int getDay();

private:
    Date birthday;
    std::string name;
    char gender;
};

Person::Person(std::string name, char gender, Date birthday){
    Person::name = name;
    Person::gender = gender;
    Person::birthday = birthday;
}
```

Class Date:

```
class Date {
public:
    Date(unsigned int y, unsigned int m, unsigned int d);
    Date(string yearMonthDay); // yearMonthDay must be in format "yyyy/mm/dd"
    void setYear(unsigned int y);
    void setMonth(unsigned int m);
    void setDay(unsigned int d);
    void setDate(unsigned int y, unsigned int m, unsigned int d);
    unsigned int getYear() const;
    unsigned int getMonth() const;
    unsigned int getDay() const;
    string getDate() const; // returns the date in format "yyyy/mm/dd"

private:
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a *constructor initializer list*:

```
Person::Person(std::string name, char gender, Date birthday){
    : name(name), gender(gender), birthday(birthday)
{
    // Empty
}
```

That will *initialize* the members only once using the arguments, calling the appropriate constructors of the members.

Without a constructor initializer list, the members will be default initialized (default constructed) and then in the body of the constructor you use normal assignment to the members.

Answer (score 1):

When you write any of your own constructors, the no-argument constructor is no longer supplied by the compiler. You can reinstate it (ask for it to be supplied) though:

```
Date() = default;
```

To make sure that you can default construct a `Date` safely, you should give proper defaults to its members:

```
private:
    unsigned int year{2000};
    unsigned int month{4};
    unsigned int day{30};
```

Comment: But only if it makes sense to do this. Which it probably doesn't.

Comment: True, I only fixed the symptom in this case. But I don't know if the answer is *wrong* per se, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings you'd be surprised how often a default ctor is needed, e.g. allocating an array of Dates or Persons.

Comment: @franji1 You'd be surprised how often a default ctor _isn't_ needed. Why are you using `new[]`?

Comment: A date is a date. It shouldn't be a not-date.